# A Complex Conditional Formatting in Excel =$H$6:$J$6 IF $I6<$J6?

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=$H$6:$J$6 +IF($I6 \\< $J6)
```

I'm finding my first formula isn't working, and was wondering if any might know what help I might need. Essentially, I need three cells to turn different colors if two of the cells are equal, < or >.

Comment: While I understand that you are comparing for two equal cells out of the three, additionally your comparison for < or > is against what values?

Comment: Thank you for your comment: if one cell is greater than another cell right next to it, color it one color. Or, if that cell is less than another cell right next to it, color it a different color.

Comment: Is it that you want any two matching cells with one color and the third non matching cell as separate color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the "IF" statement.  The "IF" is actually implied, your formula should be

```
=$I6 < $J6
```

and apply to

```
=$H$6:$J$6
```

And you'd need two similar rules for greater than and equal comparisons, of course.